# regex for alphabets with accented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I wrote a validation for first and last names:

```
validates(:name,, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/})
```

This only works for alphabets but now need to extend it with accented characters also.

- Possible pass scenarios:

  ```
  Mike
  Clark
  Chloé
  André
  ```
- Possible fail scenarios:

  ```
  Mike1
  21Clark
  André3
  Chloé#
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be too difficult to add all letter ranges as in your regex, and fortunately, it is not necessary since Ruby regex has a Unicode category class for matching all Unicode letters.

You can use

```
/\A[\p{L}\p{M}]+\z/
```

The `\p{L}` will match all Unicode letters and `\p{M}` will match all diacritics.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/O0OKdA) showing how this regex works. Here is a sample method:

```
def checkName(name)
    return /\A[\p{L}\p{M}]+\z/  =~ name ? true : false
end
```

Comment: There are former ASCII-8 accented characters, that are not handled by this regexp.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Please provide an example of such a string. What is an *ASCII-8 accented character*? I say that `\p{L}` matches all Unicode letters, and it does. If the characters are precomposed, that is enough. If they are multibyte, `\p{M}` should match the diacritics.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I for no reason took square brackets as parentheses. Please disregard.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. This is really helpful : )